# Multiple scoreboard's with node/socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to build an app that uses node/socket.io for a scorekeeper to update a form on a webpage (home/away/time) and have those results stored on the server for all clients to receive.

I'm a relatively new to node and socket.io, so would this be the best way to solve this problem?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question, however if you have an online form and you need to push notifications from the server to the clients (i.e. they see updates without having to click or reload the page), you can use socket.io, yes.